# Can I customize the Dragonfly image_uid?

Tags: ruby, upload, datastore, dragonfly-gem

I am using Dragonfly and would like to have longer filenames (**image_uid**s) that cannot be "guessed".
My current filenames look like this:

`2019/05/14/5ep7gqqmiu_test.jpg`

I'd prefer a path like this:

`2019/05/14/5ep7gqqmiun96v661gt3bdscv305xnxwzmmtr0sknwscqlxq90_test.jpg`

How can I add, for example, a random string between to the filename? I couldn't find an build-in option for this.

I tried to figure out where the job hash was created, but couldn't find the part in the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the possibility to add a custom path in the docs:

```
storage_options do |a|
  { path: "#{date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')}/#{SecureRandom.hex(64)}_#{a.name}" }
end
```

This adds a random string of 64 characters to the filename.